# Will Flutter code be reverse-engineered easily without obfuscation?

Tags: flutter, dart, reverse-engineering, obfuscation

I know Flutter is compiled AOT (ahead-of-time). However, it [seems](https://medium.com/@waytoa/obfuscating-flutter-code-and-generate-map-files-for-ios-fdaf4a377ec4) that all the method/class/field/... names will *still be visible* in the final compiled output (.apk or .ipa). I know [obfuscating](https://medium.com/@waytoa/obfuscating-flutter-code-and-generate-map-files-for-ios-fdaf4a377ec4) can use non-readable strings to replaces such names, but I cannot use it since Sentry [does not](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59321) support it well.

Thus, my question is: *Will Flutter code be reverse-engineered easily without obfuscation?* (If no, I will just disable obfuscation.)

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's possible then always assume it will be done. The question of easy or hard is dependent on who is attempting to do the reverse engineering.

Do what you can to secure your app as best you can, then if you have any sensitive logic, throw that into a backend API your app calls. If it's impossible to use an API, meaning the logic must be coded into the app that will eventually be distributed to end users, then you just hope nobody with resources notices your app.

Comment: Thanks very much! Yes I do put anything sensitive to the backend.